# Sumatoria de resultado en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Este script realiza la funcion de que cuando le doy a un botón, se me incrementa un número y en la otra parte se multiplica por el valor dado en la variable.

Lo que quiero es que los resultados finales de cada uno de ellos se me muestren en un input text. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var capnum = 0;
  var precio = capnum * 100;
  var capnum2 = 0;
  var precio2 = capnum2 * 180;

  function add(){
    capnum++;
    precio = capnum * 100;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = capnum;
    document.getElementById('mostrar').innerHTML = precio;
  }
  function add2(){
    capnum2++;
    precio2 = capnum2 * 180;
    document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = capnum2;
    document.getElementById('mostrar2').innerHTML = precio2;
  }
</script>

<button class="n" onclick="add()">AGREGAR CATEGORIA 1</button>
<p></p>
<span class="n">Cantidad:</span>
<div class="m" id="display"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(capnum);</script></div>
<span class="n">Total:</span>
<div class="m" id="mostrar"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(precio);</script></div>

<button class="n" onclick="add2()">AGREGAR CATEGORIA 2</button>
<p></p>
<span class="n">Cantidad:</span>
<div class="m" id="display2"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(capnum2);</script></div>
<span class="n">Total:</span>
<div class="m" id="mostrar2"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(precio2);</script></div>
```

Comment: Mirate el tag <input>, el atributo "value" indica su contenido.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de forma similar a como lo estás haciendo ahora mismo, sólo que en lugar de usar `innerHTML` como haces:

```
document.getElementById('mostrar').innerHTML = precio;
```

utilizarías `value` de este modo:

```
document.getElementById('mostrar').value = precio;
```

Esto es un ejemplo de cómo podría quedar el código:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  var capnum = 0;
  var precio = capnum * 100;
  var capnum2 = 0;
  var precio2 = capnum2 * 180;

  function add(){
    capnum++;
    precio = capnum * 100;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = capnum;
    document.getElementById('mostrar').innerHTML = precio;
    document.getElementById('sumatorio').value = precio + precio2;
  }
  function add2(){
    capnum2++;
    precio2 = capnum2 * 180;
    document.getElementById('display2').innerHTML = capnum2;
    document.getElementById('mostrar2').innerHTML = precio2;
    document.getElementById('sumatorio').value = precio + precio2;
  }
</script>

<button class="n" onclick="add()">AGREGAR CATEGORIA 1</button>
<p></p>
<span class="n">Cantidad:</span>
<div class="m" id="display"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(capnum);</script></div>
<span class="n">Total:</span>
<div class="m" id="mostrar"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(precio);</script></div>

<button class="n" onclick="add2()">AGREGAR CATEGORIA 2</button>
<p></p>
<span class="n">Cantidad:</span>
<div class="m" id="display2"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(capnum2);</script></div>
<span class="n">Total:</span>
<div class="m" id="mostrar2"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(precio2);</script></div>

<p>
  TOTAL SUMATORIO: <input type="text" id="sumatorio" value="0" />
  </p>
```

Comment: Lo que verdaderamente quiero es el RESULTADO de los 2 totales se me muestran en un input text

Comment: @edgar actualicé la demo para que se adapte a eso, pero la idea es la misma: usa `value` en lugar de `innerHTML`

Comment: Alvaro, gracias por tu grata colaboración, me estaba rompiendo la cabeza hasta esa parte. MUCHAS GRACIAS.

Comment: Hola @edgar, ademas de las gracias, lo cual es muy grato para todos, recuerda marcar una respuesta como aceptada. Saludos!!